# Keep Gitlab CI pipeline on single runner to ensure cache is shared

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a local gitlab server running with a few Gitlab CI runners.  In the past, we've had each runner have `concurrent = 1` setup, and then when a pipeline is run, any available runner takes any job in each stage.

However, I'd like to start caching dependencies between stages.  This means that I must ensure an entire pipeline is run within a single runner instance (I'm trying to avoid uploading caches).

Is it possible for an entire pipeline to be assigned a runner?  But have 2+ pipelines run concurrently on multiple runners?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The cache is always stored on the same location where the runner is installed and running[1]. So to share a cache across all your runners, you need to setup an S3 replacement like minio[2] and configure your runners to use that cache.
Without uploading (and downloading) the cache to a central storage, it is not possible that every runner can access the cache of another runner.

[1]https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/caching/#cache-vs-artifacts
[2]https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/registry_and_cache_servers.html#install-your-own-cache-server

> Is it possible for an entire pipeline to be assigned a runner?

Yes. Just give every runner a unique tag. Than tag every job in your pipeline with the tag of one runner. This will ensure that your pipeline will be executed only by one runner. For more see https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/runners/#using-tags

Comment: That is why my question was whether a pipeline can be constrained to a single runner.

Comment: Oh yes. Of course this is possible. Give your runner unique tags and use the same tags for all jobs in the same pipeline

Comment: I have a single defined pipeline - but it could run multiple branches at the same time.  Each "instance" (e.g. a line in the GitLab CI page) I wanted to be on the same runner.

Comment: Yeah, just tag each job. That ensure all job on all pipelines (doesn't matter which branch was the trigger) runs on the same runner.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is currently (GitLab 11.7) not possible (At least on Windows it seems) without the significant administrative overhead of assigning each runner specifically for each of your jobs. Pinning a specific runner to your project and disable all shared ones would work too.

There are a handful of issues that prevent this use case as it is not possible to share the runners cache even with a S3 blob storage configuration (we tried minio).

One of them is a race condition that prevents the cache to be extracted correctly if subsequent jobs are executed on different nodes. This is especially the case for parallel jobs.

What we tried:

1. Sharing cache using a SMB folder available on all runner machines
2. Using minio to share the cache

You can find our bug ticket here:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3920